# How to achieve a full width underscored title?

Tags: android, layout

I wanted to add to my layout section titles like phone, email and address in the image below, but cant find that built-in element, or are they just styled labels?

It's a recurring element in android default apps so I assume there must be a straightforward way to use them

Thank you so much

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be a built-in element. At least in the Contacts app, it's just a regular View:

```
<View
  android:id="@+id/divider"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1px"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
  android:layout_marginStart="8dip"
  android:layout_marginEnd="8dip"
  android:background="@color/secondary_header_separator_color" />
```

So, just a one-pixel-high view with a specific background color.

You can see the layout in the [Contacts app source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/res/layout/item_read_only_field.xml). The text style used for the header is in the [styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/res/values/styles.xml) file.

```
<style name="EditKindTextAppearanceStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
  <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#363636</item>
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind telling me as well where I can find the header format that's right before the divider element? (Since it's not in the source link you provided) :)

Comment: @Dane411 Added snippet with the style, hope that's what you needed!